# Latex compilation problem

Tags: latex

I have installed latex and compiled tex file using pdflatex command, the file did not compile. It is showing revtex4-1.cls not found. How to fix this, please any one can help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The missing file is in [texlive-publishers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/all/texlive-publishers/filelist).

Please try `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers` and run `pdflatex` again.

Comment: not running the link,showing msg like this;
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Are you're having Synaptic or the SoftwareCenter running?

Comment: no. earlier some installation was running, but quit in between. Is that causing / preventing?

Comment: That would have been a reason. We can't install with diffrent tools at the same time or install while updating/upgrading.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. I have installed texlive-publishers and working well. thanks again

Comment: Great! I'm glad we could figure that out so fast!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Klaus-DieterWarzecha . I also had similar problem (in Ubuntu 14.04). Then installed texlive-publishers. When compiled, I get another error: LaTeX Error: File `mhchem.sty' not found.  How this can be solved?